# How do Embed node-red into AdonisJS?

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I am new to AdonisJS, but it seems like its the one with the least learning curve. However, my next project requires node-red, the following link has instructions for embedding into an express app... the structure of course is completely different from AdonisJS.

Any hints on how to integrate it into Adonis?

https://nodered.org/docs/embedding

Comment: i think you can start looking at folder Start > app.js file and integrate from there by serving pre-configured nodered settings

Comment: sorry for not replying sooner. I was on another project so this took back burner.

I guess it needs some changes with adonisjs.
1) it doesn't use express?
2) the format is not like the documentation above

I am a bit new to node, but appears this framework format is different than expressjs based ones?